# YouTube loading with WebView doesn't work

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

1. I used to play youtube in my iOS app with the HTML string as below.
2. I used to load the HTML as

   `[webView loadHTMLString:fileContents baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];`
3. Suddenly it has stopped working. The only way it works is if I set the baseURL to a http URL like "http://www.example.com". I want to know what is the correct baseURL to set.

   ```
    <div id='container'>
       <div id="child">
           <div id="player"></div>
       </div>
   </div>

   <script>
       var tag = document.createElement('script');
       tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

       var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

       var player;
       function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
           player = new YT.Player('player', {
                                  width: '%@',
                                  height: '%@',
                                  videoId: '%@',
                                  playerVars: {
                                  origin: 'file://',
                                  showinfo: 0,
                                  controls: 0,
                                  playsinline: 1,
                                  autoplay: 1
                                  },
                                  events: {
                                  'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                                  'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
                                  'onPlaybackQualityChange': onPlayerPlaybackQualityChange,
                                  'onPlaybackRateChange': onPlayerPlaybackRateChange,
                                  'onError': onPlayerError,
                                  'onApiChange': onPlayerApiChange
                                  }
                                  });
       }

       // Event functions
       function onPlayerReady(event) {
           onEvent('ready', null);
       }

       function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
           onEvent('stateChange', playerStateToString(event.data));
       }

       function onPlayerPlaybackQualityChange(event) {
           onEvent('playbackQuality', event.data);
       }

       function onPlayerPlaybackRateChange(event) {
           onEvent('playbackRateChange', event.data);
       }

       function onPlayerError(event) {
           onEvent('error', event.data);
       }

       function onPlayerApiChange(event) {
           onEvent('apiChange', event.data);
       }

       function onEvent(eventName, eventData) {
           var url = "ytplayer://event/" + eventName;
           if (eventData != null) {
               url += ('/' + eventData);
           }
           document.location = url;
       }

       // Helpers
       function playerStateToString(playerState) {
           var result = null;
           switch (playerState) {
               case -1:
               result = "unstarted";
               break;
               case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
               result = "ended";
               break;
               case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
               result = "playing";
               break;
               case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
               result = "paused";
               break;
               case YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING:
               result = "buffering";
               break;
               case YT.PlayerState.CUED:
               result = "cued";
               break;
           }
           return result;
       }
       </script>
   ```

   "

Answer (score 0):

I use "about:blank". This value just cannot be null or NONE.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]] which will translate to something like /var/Applications/App%20Name on real device. Do you know if this is not allowed ?